# How to display the URL of the current document in Blackberry Phonegap, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, cordova, blackberry-simulator

How to display the URL of the current document in Blackberry Phonegap using Javascript? I tried to display the current document's url, but it shows nearly 1,000 lines of encrypted text. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Display where? What did you try? Give us more info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried alert(location.href)?